# Suppose that $A$ and $C$ are invertible matrices, and that $ABC = I$. Show $B = A^{−1}C^{ −1}$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I'm working through the problem and I start with $ABC = I = (AC)B = I... B = (AC)^{-1}$.. This is equal to $B = C^{-1} * A^{-1}$. However, I'm trying to show that $B = A^{-1} * C^{-1}$. Where am I going wrong? I feel as if I'm going in the right direction, but can't seem to tie it together.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format.

Comment: What makes you think that $\operatorname{Id}=(AC)B$?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative.  And that is what it looks like you are trying to do.  That is, you cannot swap $B$ and $C$ in $ABC$.  But you can multiply  $(ABC)$ and $I$ by $A^{-1}$ on the left side and $C^{-1}$ on the right side.  That is $A^{-1}ABCC^{-1} = A^{-1}I C^{-1}$ and simplify.

Comment: I edited your title to get the exponents right.  Cheers!

Comment: @Doug M  Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138).

Answer (score 2):

$ABC=I$

$A^{-1}ABC=A^{-1}I$

$BC=A^{-1}$

$BCC^{-1}=A^{-1}C^{-1}$

$B=A^{-1}C^{-1}$.